# installing AWS ios sdk in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, sdk

I'm trying to add the AWS SDK to my xcode project that is written in swift.

I followed these steps: http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AA7ZHB1FK0G1/Version-2-of-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-Developer-Preview to create a Bridge-Header file, and add the SDK itself to my project.

The problem is that when I try to build the app I get an error now... the Bridge Header cannot be imported because one of the files in the AWS SDK (AWSModel.h) has an error. This file tries to import Mantle/Mantle.h, and the error reads "Mantle/Mantle.h file not found"

do I need to add this file to my project as well? If so, how would I go about doing that? The only frameworks I'm using are Facebook SDK, and I would like to add AWS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working sample app on [GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/SNS-MobileAnalytics-Sample/Swift). You should follow README and see if you can compile the app. It should help you understand how to set up the project.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong.. I had not included the third party files.

Comment: on another note, I hit a bigger issue this evening, and have asked a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244484/aws-ios-sdk-uploading-objects-to-aws-s3   and for this one I tried to implement the same logic that you described here: http://mobile.awsblog.com/blog/author/Yosuke+Matsuda but have not been successful thus far. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: link is no longer exists.